# Redirecting sub-domain to specific URI

Tags: redirect, dns, subdomain, domain-forwarding

I want to redirect my subdomain to specific URI without making any changes to my code.

I found the domain forwarding services from Bigrock, they have a sub-domain forwarding service which specifies all subdomains will be redirected as "subdomain.mydomain.com to yourdestinationurl/subdomain/"

I replaced yourdestinationurl, with www.mydomain.com but it's not working.

Am I doing something wrong?Is there any alternative way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You may create the subdomain in the DNS Manager/Domain name zone file and point it to any URL using 'URL-Redirect' DNS record.

In other words, you need to login into the account of your domain name registrar (if the domain name is delegated to the default nameservers) or into your hosting cPanel (if you have a hosting plan). Then you need to find where to configure DNS records and configure URL-Redirect (also called URL-Forwarding) for your subdomain.

There is no need to have any plugins.